# Websphere 8.5 Installation - Windows Vista Administrative Privileges Error on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, installation, websphere, windows-vista

I'm installing WebSphere 8.5 for developers on my local computer, and I'm running into an error message A screenshot and the message is listed below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/56jx5.jpg

> "To run an application without administrative privileges on the Windows Vista operating >system, you must install the application package into a directory that is not virtualized. >The Program Files directory on Windows Vista is virtualized. To run an application with >administrative privileges after it is installed, right-click the package, and click "Run as >administrator"."

I'm actually on Windows 8 (64-bit), so this is a bit odd. How do I defeat this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello,
Install it into non virtualized directory (so not into Program Files).
It's always the best to use the shortest path possible, when installing Java based stuff on Windows. I prefer C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [System requirements page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038218) suggests WebSphere Application Server for Developers 8.5.5 being supports Microsoft Windows 8. 
WebSphere Application Server 8.5.0.1 seems to have [introduced Windows 8 support](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1307977887217&osPlatform=Windows#fixpack-Server) as well.